# convert vector to jobject in C++/JNI?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am using Java native function -

```
public native ArrayList<String> parseXML();
```

In C++ my native function -

```
vector<string> resultList;

JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_Sample1_parseXML
(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj){
   // logic
   return resultList;   // here getting error
}
```

My problem is that how to convert resultList (vector type) to jobject type?

Comment: +1: It a lot harder than you might imagine. ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You would have to create a wrapper for the ArrayList in C++. Something like:

```
vector <char*> vec;

jclass clazz = (*env).FindClass("java/util/ArrayList");
jobject obj = (*env).NewObject(clazz, (*env).GetMethodID(clazz, "<init>", "()V"));

for (int n=0;n<vec.size();n++)
{
   char* str = (char*) static_cast<char*>(vec[n]);

   jstring _str = (*env).NewStringUTF(str);

   (*env).CallVoidMethod(object, (*env).GetMethodID(clazz, "add", "(java/lang/Object)V"), _str);

}

return obj;
```

for further information see:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html

Comment: Nice answer. But it would be absolutely great, if someone writes an adapter for STL `vector` that implements `java.util.List`. Quite fascinating exercise!

Comment: Right! This would be the solution of the solutions.

Comment: Pardon my pedantry, but isn't `(char*)static_cast<char*>` redundant?

Comment: By the way, in CallVoidMethod, what is tha object parameter exactly? I mean as I found out, that should be a jobject. If I try to do the same as above, the compiler says, that object isn't declared in the scope.

Comment: what is the "object" in CallVoidMethod() and where are we using "jobject obj " declared at the top of code?

Answer (score 9):

The method is:

```
bool add(Object);
```

So the signature is:

```
"(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z"
```

More at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/types.html#wp276

```
vector <char*> vec;

jclass clazz = (*env).FindClass("java/util/ArrayList");
jobject obj = (*env).NewObject(clazz, (*env).GetMethodID(clazz, "<init>", "()V"));
for (int n=0;n<vec.size();n++)
{
    char* str = (char*) static_cast<char*>(vec[n]);
    jstring _str = (*env).NewStringUTF(str);
    (*env).CallBooleanMethod(object, (*env).GetMethodID(clazz, "add", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z"), _str);
}
return obj;
```

Comment: This looks like an almost character-by-character copy of the first answer.

Comment: @moshbear: it's not. `CallBooleanMethod` here, `CallVoidMethod` there. The rest is rather mechanical, so similarities are expected.

Comment: Fair enough. My comment on the previous answer w.r.t. `(char*)static_cast<char*>` being redundant still stands, though.

Comment: what is the "object" in CallVoidMethod() and where are we using "jobject obj " declared at the top of code?