# Using JNA to access a struct containing a vector<char*>

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, jna

I have a C++ library that uses a struct which contains a vector. I am having some difficulty determining the correct way to access this from Java via JNA.

My C++ structure:

```
#include <vector>

struct topic {
    char* src_id;
    char* dest_id;
    int32_t num;
    std::vector<char*> names;
};
```

My Java class:

```
public final class Topic extends Structure {

    public String src_id;
    public String dest_id;
    public int num;
    public String[] names; // This doesn't work

    public Topic() {

    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList(new String[] { "src_id", "dest_id", "num", "names" });
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776800/convert-vector-to-jobject-in-c-jni/7777198) helps? I am sadly not really familiar with c++

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't work for me. I need to make it work just with JNA.

Comment: Well another thing i noticed is that you use a `Vector` in c++ but an array in java, what happens when you use an array in c++ too?

Comment: @Lino It shouldn't matter because vector is a managed array. It just knows additional info like size and has additional capabilities. But when it comes to accessing memory contents both are similar

Comment: @SolidMercury So it's like an `ArrayList` in java, my thought behind the array thing was, that I am not entirely sure, that JNI will know how to directly convert from a `std::vector` to an array. Just a speculation though

Comment: May be this will help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972207/passing-string-array-from-java-to-c-with-jni

Comment: @SolidMercury Thanks, but I need to make it work with JNA.

Comment: @FernandoLozano I have done little coding with JNI. JNA is new to me and even I am trying to figure that out. You could give a try with public StringArray(String[] strings). Refer https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.0/com/sun/jna/StringArray.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution worked for me:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.StringArray;
import com.sun.jna.Structure;

public class Example {

    public interface CLibrary extends Library {

        public static class Topic extends Structure {
            public static class ByReference extends Topic implements Structure.ByReference {
            }

            public String src_id;
            public String dest_id;
            public int num;

            public int numVals;
            public Pointer names; // char**

            @Override
            protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
                return Arrays.asList(new String[] { "src_id", "dest_id", "num", "numVals", "names" });
            }
        }

        public void sendTopic(Topic.ByReference pVal);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final CLibrary clib = Native.loadLibrary("example.dll", CLibrary.class);

        final String[] myArray = new String[5];
        myArray[0] = "one";
        myArray[1] = "two";
        myArray[2] = "three";
        myArray[3] = "four";
        myArray[4] = "five";

        CLibrary.Topic.ByReference ref = new CLibrary.Topic.ByReference();
        ref.numVals = 5;
        ref.names = new StringArray(myArray);

        clib.sendTopic(ref);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does that mean my suggestion over comment helped you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pointer and pass StringArray using `public StringArray(String[] strings)` as mentioned [here](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.0/com/sun/jna/StringArray.html)

```
public String src_id;
public String dest_id;
public int num;
public Pointer names;

String[] namesArray= new String[2];
//Assign two names to namesArray

//Construct StringArray with namesArray and pass it to Pointer
names = new StringArray(namesArray);
```