# Is this allowed at runtime? How do you extract the top N elements of a stack-like thing?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to do something like this - copy the top N elements of the stack to an array. I want to use it to define the invokevirtual, invokespecial, invokestatic, invokeinterface, and invokedynamic instructions for a Java Ahead-Of-Time Compiler. The stack is a linked list and __pop() unwinds and returns the top of the stack.

```cpp
    public : void __sipop(){
        topframe = topframe->prev;
    }
    public : void __longpop(){
        topframe = topframe->prev->prev;
    }
    public : jvalue __pop(){
        //also shared with bytecode
        jvalue value = topframe->value;
        if(topframe->type == 'J' || topframe->type == 'D'){
            __longpop();
        } else{
            __sipop();
        }
        return value;
    }
    public : jvalue* __extract(int count){
        jvalue extracted [count];
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            extracted[count - i - 1] = __pop();
        }
        return extracted;
    }
```

Will my implementation crash at runtime?

Comment: are you writing a C++ implementation? Because [names starting with double underscores (`__`) are reserved](https://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/995714)

Comment: `jvalue extracted [count];` - looks like a VLA and is not allowed in standard C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will my implementation crash at runtime?

Maybe. You exhibit Undefined Behaviour at least in:

```
jvalue* __extract(int count){
    jvalue extracted [count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        extracted[count - i - 1] = __pop();
    }
    return extracted;
}
```

Your function returns a pointer to a local variable whose lifetime ends as the function returns. For additional information, you should read this excellent answer on Sotack Overflow: [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/5470596) (tl; dr: no).

The simplest solution would be to return a vector:

```
#include <vector> // preferably in the first lines of your header file (.hpp)

std::vector<jvalue> extract(int count)
{
    auto extracted = std::vector<jvalue>(count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        extracted[count - i - 1] = __pop();
    }
    return extracted;
}
```

You may also be interested by [`std::generate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate).

---

Additionally, as mentioned in the comments, names staring by two underscores (`__`) are reserved to the implementation.

Unrelated note, I understand your wish to feel comfortable in C++ by mimicking aspects of the Java language, but you should write idiomatic C++ and not repeat the access modifier (`public`) before each member function.

Comment: I changed it to ````jvalue* extracted = new jvalue[count];```` and my GCC compiler stopped warning me about it.

Comment: @JessieLesbian You shouldn't unless you have a good reason to avoid vectors. You're basically opening a can of worms by recurring to dynamic memory. And if you do, you **must** learn how to handle such memory, how and when to use `delete[]`, what _memory ownership_ means, what RAII is, etc.

Comment: @JessieLesbian Don't do that - you loose the size information and need to manually `delete[]` the allocated memory. Prefer a `std::vector<jvalue>`.

Comment: First, i'm avoiding vectors since I have to pass it to JNI. Second, the calling method knows exactly how long the array is going to be.

Comment: @JessieLesbian You can create a Java ArrayList from a C++ vector: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7776800/5470596

Comment: I mean, I'm dealing with this sort of signature: ````void (JNICALL *CallStaticVoidMethodA)
      (JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jmethodID methodID, const jvalue * args);````, which don't like vectors.

Comment: @JessieLesbian Anyway, this is another question you should ask as a new question. There might be solutions combining the best of the two worlds (e.g. you can access a vector's memory with its `.data` member function).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Returning the address of a stack-local object (`extracted`) is undefined behavior. Return a heap-allocated array (`auto extracted = new jvalue[count];`) or `std::vector<jvalue>` instead.

Comment: I changed it to ````jvalue* extracted = new jvalue[count];````. Will this work as well?

Comment: Yes. The caller is responsible for calling `delete[] extracted;` or you will have a memory leak.